# return the content of a request using callback in node.js?

Tags: node.js

How to return the content of a request using callback in node.js ? 
I would like to make the program to wait until it has fetched the result of the inner callback requestCallBack, hence i have put an await keyword infront of requestCallback inside the request function, but it has no effect. I know it can work with promises, I just want to practice callbacks in node.js.

```
const getData = url => {
  return  await request(url, await requestCallBack);
};

const requestCallBack = async (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    return body;
  }
};
```

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense, if you want to turn a Node callback function into a promise, use https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Answer (score 0):

The Request library does not return a Promise

async-await will work with those libraries only which return a Promise

Use Node-Fetch instead

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Then inside some async function...

const response = await fetch(`${YOUR_API}`, {
        method: 'GET', // or POST or whatever
        headers: {
                "Some-key": "Some-value"
        }
});

const responseJson = await response.json();

// Apply exception handling
```

Also practicing callbacks, syntactically is...

```
// Define
const someAsyncFn = (x, y, callback) => {
        ...
        ...
        // After work's done, invoke callback
        callback();
}

// Invoke
someAsyncFn("some-val", "another-val", () => {

        // Things to do in the callback
        ...
        ...
})

// Also you can parameterize the callback function
```